# fatal error: libavfilter/avfiltergraph.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, build, libav, screen-recording

I am trying to build this project:
https://github.com/abdullahfarwees/screen-recorder-ffmpeg-cpp.
I installed ffmpeg (following the instructions in the repo README). After that I tried to compile (using the command in the compile.sh file) with correct paths.
I received the following error:

```
In file included from src/main.cpp:2:
src/../include/ScreenRecorder.h:23:10: fatal error: libavfilter/avfiltergraph.h: No such file or directory
   23 | #include "libavfilter/avfiltergraph.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from src/ScreenRecorder.cpp:1:
src/../include/ScreenRecorder.h:23:10: fatal error: libavfilter/avfiltergraph.h: No such file or directory
   23 | #include "libavfilter/avfiltergraph.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I installed the libavfilter library.
Does anyone know how to fix this? Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

avfiltergraph.h was merged into avfilter.h in [this commit](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/38f0c0781a6e099f11c0acec07f9b8be742190c4)

You should either use a version before that, or create a dummy libavfilter/avfiltergraph.h that contains:

```
#include "libavfilter/avfilter.h"
```

I also suggest you report this issue to the project you're trying to compile, ideally with a pull request :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to do what you suggested, but I received several errors

Comment: If that code is targeting a version of FFmpeg that has not been updated in 8 years, it stands to reason other parts have bitrotted as well. I don't think this question is the right place to have someone fix the code for you. You will have to put in some effort yourself.

Comment: Yes I get it. I have never used ffmpeg. I'm trying to understand it but the documentation is pretty poor